# With node.js, do you actually write your business logic in js or it makes calls to your service layer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, node.js

When using node.js to e.g. serve requests for a backbone.js front end, would node.js actually have your applications business logic or would it make calls out to your web service backend written in say Rails or Java?

If it makes calls out to Rails/Java, how would this be done?  Confused as it is single threaded.

Comment: I know this question is more open-ended than we usually have here on The Stack, but after reading [rants about silly algorithms in Node.js](http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2011/10/nodejs-has-jumped-shark.html) as a stand-in for actual business work, I've found myself wondering if Node is mainly used as glue or if it does the work itself for most users...

Comment: If you make calls to an external service, you're likely either making an HTTP request (which runs asynchronously) or forking a child process (which is also asynchronous).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your business logic will be written in Javascript. I use Node.js + Backbone.js in conjunction with each other on two different projects. Node is great for writing a backend ReSTful API quick and easy and Backbone.js is great for keeping my client side logic organized.

Like any web tech, a separation between client/server is still essential, but Node allows you to think/write in one language and use the same libraries both server and client side. There are many advantages to this in small shops, as the there is no longer a divide between the "front end" guys and the "back end" guys.

Node's single threaded nature is a turn off to a lot of new comers... its easily overcome with multiple proc instances and a load balancer. (If you even need all that... Node is built on an event model and can handle quite the load before you need to think about running another instance... of course this is completely dependent upon if you're writing good asynchronous code)

Is this to say Node.js + Backbone.js is the best answer for YOUR project? No. But you should weigh out the advantages of using Node over Rails/Java/PHP/Python before you make a decision. For me it was simple when considering RAD... one language, one set of libs... its my favorite web stack thus far.

Comment: +1 for "Is this to say Node.js + Backbone.js is the best answer for YOUR project?" Is Node going to hang up over your business logic if it's "is this user's password right" or "should this user have access to this page?" No. But if it's "calculate the best chess move" or some other computationally expensive task, you'll need to do something about it.

Comment: @BrandonTilley, while computationally-intensive tasks should be done with a service layer, there isn't--at least while we're free of specifics-- any reason you can't implement that layer on Node. I know you didn't explicitly say otherwise, but given the question, it seemed good to clarify.